# Verify C++11 library compliance for clang (mavericks)

Tags: xcode, c++11, osx-mavericks, ld, clang++

How can I verify exactly which library, particularly of the standard library, that clang++ links to? Once I do, how can I verify that this is the correct C++11 library and not an earlier version (i.e. is there executable code that tests that).

clang -v only gives the library search paths, not the actual library that was linked to. I am concerned the right library is being shadowed, as I am getting very odd behavior (for instance, once C++11 style initialization to a vector, like vector v {5, 6} , failed at run time, silently, just initializing v to zeros, but I was never able to reproduce this).

Someone said on another thread that kind of thing can be caused by an upgrade rather than clean install of Mavericks, but I want to check the libraries first.

Note that most of the StackOverflow responses about std libraries on Apple pertain to earlier versions of the OS; Apple apparently completely changed things in Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ldd.
e.g.,
ldd /path/to/clang

```
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2f1ff000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fea7eec8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fea7ecc3000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fea7ea80000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fea7e863000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fea7e64b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /pkg/qct/software/gnu64/gcc/4.8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fea7e33c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fea7e0b9000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /pkg/qct/software/gnu64/gcc/4.8.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fea7dea1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fea7db1b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fea7f0f5000)
```

Comment: That's helpful, it turns out that ldd is not on mac, but a search showed "otool -L" solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Mac command for finding the linked libraries is "otool -L". As to verifying if a particular library is C++11 compliant, I do not know.